# Translating "the nature of man" in Ancient Greek

Tags: greek, syntax

As far as I know, *the nature of man* could be translated in at least two ways in Attic Greek:

> 1. ἡ φῠ́σῐς τοῦ ἀνθρώπου
> 2. ἡ τοῦ φῠ́σῐς ἀνθρώπου

The second version seems to have been more idiomatic in Ancient Greek; so my question is whether or not this is true; and also if both versions are grammatically correct.

Comment: Are you sure about the second one? I don't recall seeing that. I would perhaps write ἡ τοῦ ἀνθρώπου φῠ́σῐς.

Comment: Agreed, ἡ τοῦ ἀνθρώπου φῠ́σῐς is also possible, but not ἡ τοῦ φῠ́σῐς ἀνθρώπου. TLG is down for me right now but I'll check it later and see which was more common, though I suspect the first.

Comment: And in .1. isn't the definite article repeated? ἡ φῠ́σῐς ἡ τοῦ ἀνθρώπου.

Answer (score 5):

As an ancient Greek teacher I can tell you that the sentence #1 is correct. But #2 although it is grammatically correct, it's syntax is not. The sentence that would be the best translation in Attic is the ἡ τοῦ ἀνθρώπου φῠ́σῐς (it's grammar AND syntax are both correct and also sounds better).